# Passing array from view(Blade) to another view(Blade) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have master layout of laravel blade template `main.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@yield('title','My Site')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('container','Content area')

    {{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.js') }}

</body>
</html>
```

I extended it for another view `index.blade.php`

```
@extend('main')
```

I want to add javascript links to master layout(`main.blade.php`) if exists in child layout(`index.blade.php`)

added code in `index.blade.php`

```
$extraJs = array('plugins1.js','plugins2.js');

@section('extraJs')
{{ $extraJs }}
@stop
```

So, How can I add javascript to master layout if exists in child blade?

In php:

```
<?php 
if(isset($extraJs)): 
foreach($extraJs as $js):
?>
<script src="assets/js/<?php echo $js ?>" type="text/javascript" />
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a yield in your `main.blade.php`, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@yield('title','My Site')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('container','Content area')

    {{ HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.js') }}

    @yield('javascripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in your child layout, you add a section for it, like you did. For example:

```
@section('javascripts')
    @foreach($scripts as $script)
        {{ HTML::script('ets/js/' . $script) }}
    @endforeach
@stop
```

If you add another child view which doesn't need to use extra javascripts, Laravel won't complain because the section is optional.

Comment: Thanks, I can add by 

@section('javascripts') 
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/js1.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/js/js2.js') }}
@stop

But, Can I do this by passing just file name in Array?

like, $extraJs = array('js1.js','js2.js');

Which auto-populates in main.blde.php

{{ HTML::script('ets/js/js2.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('ets/js/js2.js') }}

Comment: You can't send them upwards, so to speak, as far as I'm aware. If you want to do that, you're probably better off using view composers. But you could do it in the subview, of course - see my edited example.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really encourage this method but since you asked. It is definitely possible to pass something "up" in the view tree. You can just define a PHP variable in your view and it will be available anywhere in the layout.

#### index.blade.php

```
<?php $extraJs = array('plugins1.js','plugins2.js'); ?>
```

#### main.blade.php

```
@if(isset($extraJs))
    @foreach($extraJs as $js)
        <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/'.$js) }}" type="text/javascript" />
    @endforeach
@endif
```

As you can see I also converted your code in the layout to blade and made use of the `asset()` function to generate absolute URLs

**Note** Instead of doing it this way there are other methods. For example [View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers) or defining the plugins in the controller.